# Wrong uderstanding of lambda functions ? [Expected body of lambda expression on my anonymous function]

Tags: android, c++11, closures, c++builder, anonymous-function

I'm currently trying to use lambda functions to handle a listener events.

At first I was getting these two errors on my first lambda function :

`timer->Enabled` is interpreted as coming from `this` though it comes from the capture/closure of the lambda function, with the message `[bccaarm Erreur] ScanManager.cpp(128): 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context`

And

```
[bccaarm Erreur] ScanManager.cpp(117): assigning to 'TNotifyDecodeEvent' (aka 'void (__closure
*)(Atid::Dev::Barcode::_di_JBarcodeType, Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::_di_JString)
__attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))') from incompatible type '<lambda at ScanManager.cpp:117:32>'
```

So I added `__attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))` before the bracket of the body of my anonymous function.
But then I got the error `Expected body of lambda expression`.

**Anonymous function 1 :**

```
void TScanManager::setOnScanCallBack(Scan * scan, TTimer * timer,TMediaPlayer * MediaPlayer1){
    if(this->hasAtidScanner){
        TAJBarcodeEventListener * ScanListener = new TAJBarcodeEventListener();

        ScanListener->OnDecodeEvnt = [scan, timer, MediaPlayer1](_di_JBarcodeType typeCB, _di_JString code)__attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp"))){
            Global->ScanManager->scanEnabled = false;

            scan->barcode = JStringToString(code);
            scan->typecode = JStringToString(typeCB->toString());
            //Si un code a ete lu
            if(scan->barcode != ""){
                Global->addToLog(String("Code Barre: ") + scan->barcode);
                if((Global->utilisateur->mode & 1) != 1){
                    utile->beep(MediaPlayer1, true);
                }
                timer->Enabled = true;
            }
            else{
                Global->ScanManager->scanEnabled = true;
            }

        };

        this->AtidBarcodeEventListenerList->AddObject(Now(), (TObject*) ScanListener);
        this->ScanAtid->setEventListener(_di_JBarcodeEventListener(*ScanListener));
    }else{


    }
}
```

I also get the error `'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context` on my use of my timer variable on my second anonymous function :

**Anonymous function 2 :**

```
std::function<void(TObject* const, TMessageBase* const)> TScanManager::cameraScanCallBack(Scan * scan, TTimer * timer){
    return [scan, timer](TObject* const sender, TMessageBase* const m){
        TMessageResultNotification* msg = dynamic_cast<TMessageResultNotification*>(m);
        if(msg){
            //Recuperation du retour de l'application de scanner
            _di_JIntent data = msg->Value;
            TMessageManager::DefaultManager->Unsubscribe(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), Global->ScanManager->cameraScanMsgID);
            Global->ScanManager->cameraScanMsgID = 0;
            scan->barcode = "";
            Global->addToLog("Passage par retourScanTel");

            if(msg->RequestCode == 0){
                if(msg->ResultCode == TJActivity::JavaClass->RESULT_OK){
                    if(data){
                        //Recuperation du code-barres
                        scan->barcode = JStringToString(data->getStringExtra(StringToJString("SCAN_RESULT")));

                        //Recuperation du type de code-barres
                        scan->typecode = JStringToString(data->getStringExtra(StringToJString("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT")));

                        //Verifie si le code-barres comporte des codes fonctions
                        if(scan->typecode == "CODE_128" && scan->barcode.SubString(0,3) == "]C1"){
                            scan->typecode = "Fonction";
                            scan->barcode = scan->barcode.SubString(3, scan->barcode.Length() - 3);
                        }
                        //Declenchement du timer de decodage
                        timer->Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            delete msg;
        }
    };
}
```

What am I missing ? Are my closures wrong ?
Why does this `this` error shows up on the timer variable and not the scan variable ? Is this related to sync problematics between threads (thread of the anonymous function and TTimer initialized and handled by the form) ?

Comment: "*'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context*" - so simply add `this` to your lambda's capture list so it is captured explicitly.  And do not add an `__attribute__` to your lambda at all

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau , yes I added `this` to both functions and it solved the error about `this`, but I still get the same `assigning to 'TNotifyDecodeEvent' ...` error. Is my closure incompatible with `__closure *`  ?  
I also tried `[this,scan, timer, MediaPlayer1]  (_di_JBarcodeType typeCB, _di_JString code) -> void ` resulting in the same error.

Previously this function was a method of an object and was defined by `void __fastcall onDecode(_di_JBarcodeType typeCB, _di_JString code);` and it worked fine. 

I don't get the error.

Comment: This error only happens for the 1st anonymous, not the second.

Comment: You cannot use a lambda for a `__closure`, they are not compatible with each other. You must use a non-static class method. A `__closure` consists of 2 pointers, one for the `this` object, and one for the method address.  A lambda does not satisfy that requirement. That is what the error message is saying: "*assigning to 'TNotifyDecodeEvent' ... from **incompatible type** '<lambda>'*"

Comment: Ok thanks Remy. I'm going for another solution :)